# DataMapper DateTime conditions

Tags: ruby, datetime, sinatra, datamapper

I'm using a simple Sinatra web app with a DataMapper MySql db. I declared a Datamapper `Post` class with property

```
property :created_at, DateTime
```

(initialized with `Time.now`) and now want to get the count of all posts from the last 7 days. My queries

```
lastweek_posts = Post.count(:created_at.gte => 1.week.ago)
lastweek_posts = Post.count(:conditions => ["created_at >= ?", Time.now.utc - 1.week])
```

however all return a count of 0 (database contains several entries with a created_at of today). What would be the correct query?

Many thanks in advance!

Update:

```
Post.all(:created_at.gte => 1.week.ago).length
```

returns the correct value, this is however a bad alternative as it would fetch all posts from my remote sql database.

Comment: Both queries are right and work perfectly for me.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! That's strange, could this probably be an internal issue with the mysql adapter with datetime/time data type conversion?

Comment: Check what Post.all returns, see if you can get the same result by counting on ruby side. It also may depend on adapter, try to change column type to Time (maps to TIMESTAMP, that is recommended type for storing time).

Comment: Thank you, see my update above, a fetch in combination with a ruby count returns the correct value. So this is probably a bug with DataMapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the error, I simply missed to require `dm-aggregates` in my Sinatra script as clearly stated in the [docs under 'Counting'](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html).

I'm sorry for this one!